# np.array with inhomogeneos data (str+float)

Tags: python, numpy

i'am importing data from excel. The matrix is a mix of floats (or strings that are convertable to floats) and strings and I need to do operations with the floats, ignoring the strings.  How can i set the strings to 0?

Example:
i have an array a:
    a = np.array(['1','.5','day'],['month','.5','7.3'])

I want to convert that array to:
    a = ([1,.5,0],[0,.5,7.3])

edit:
it worked out for me with the following code:

```
shape = np.shape(a)
for i in range(shape[0]):
    for j in range(shape[1]):
        if np.core.defchararray.isdigit((np.core.defchararray.replace(a[i,j],'.','')))==False:
            a[i,j]=0

a=np.array(a,float)
```

Comment: How are loading it?  'Genfromtxt' lets you specify columns.

Comment: i use xlrd.open_workbook. Specifying columns would not help, i think, because there are columns where measuring data is mixed with text (like "no measurement").

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using a combination of [`np.core.defchararray.replace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.replace.html) and [`np.core.defchararray.isdigit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.isdigit.html) -

```
a[~np.core.defchararray.isdigit(np.core.defchararray.replace(a,'.',''))]=0
out = a.astype(float)
```

Sample run -

```
In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
array([['1', '.5', 'day'],
       ['month', '.5', '7.3']], 
      dtype='|S5')

In [3]: a[~np.core.defchararray.isdigit(np.core.defchararray.replace(a,'.',''))] = 0

In [4]: a.astype(float)
Out[4]: 
array([[ 1. ,  0.5,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.5,  7.3]])
```

Comment: That does not work ('numpy.str_' does not support the buffer interface). I tried an similar approach before, but isdigit returns false for elements like '.5'

Comment: @derh That's why I added `np.core.defchararray.replace(a,'.','')` to remove the decimal point before feeding it to `isdigit`. Did you try the entire code as it is?

Comment: @derh Also what is the datatype of input `a`?

Comment: ah, okay, that makes sense! The code doesn't work, but i will try to use the idea. thank you!

Comment: a is an array of strings

Comment: @derh In my case, I assumed `S5 dtype`. You can find that out with `a.dtype`.